# Rename all the files in the folder including sub folders

Tags: file, rename

I have a requirement to rename all files in a folder (including subfolders) by adding the last modified time in the original file name.

For Example...  `filename.txt` and last modified time is  `01/02/2018 7:10` then the new file should be renamed as `filename_20180201_0710_V1.txt`

The script should change all the files in the folder and subfolders.

Thanks

Regards,
Gowtham

Comment: what technology do you use?

Comment: Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I have done script via VB,